# Installing Ad Hoc Build on PC

Tags: iphone, itunes

How do I install ad hoc build on a PC?

I'm following the tutorial from this url http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution

However, my iTunes doesn't seem to have "Application" under "Library".

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I got it. Just need to drag it to "Library" and the "App" icon will show up.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

To install an ad-hoc build of your application, follow these steps:

1. Connect your device to your computer. iTunes will open.
2. Drag and drop both the provisioning profile and the application binary to the Library section. The Library section will be highlighted with a blue border.
3. Select your device in iTunes and click Sync.

After performing these steps, you will find an icon for your application on the desktop of your device.